# Then $G $ will form a Choose the correct option

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G =\{f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; \text{f continuous} \}$
with respect to the operation defined by $(f.g)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1].$ Then  $G $ will form a

Choose the correct option

$a)$ Group

$b)$ ring

$c)$ field

$d)$ None of these

i don't know how to approached this  kinds  of problem

any hints/solution

thanks  u

Comment: The process of elimination is one way to go: i.e., you can check to see if $G$ satisfies the properties of a group. If a) fails, then what can you say about the other options?

Comment: You may first want to look into the definitions of groups, rings and fields. For example, start with the fact that you have been given ONLY ONE binary operation on the set. Does that tell you something?